# How does Python remember the number of decimal places one used to specify a float?

Tags: python, floating-point

Today it was pointed out to me that 0.99 can't be represented by a float:

```py
num = 0.99
print('{0:.20f}'.format(num))
```

prints `0.98999999999999999112`. I'm fine with this concept.

So then how does python know to do this:

```py
num = 0.99
print(num)
```

prints `0.99`.

Comment: It's not *remembering*. It's looking at the value it's got and deciding the best way to present it, which it thinks in this case is 0.99 because the value is as close as possible to 0.99. If you `print(0.98999999999999999112)` it will show `0.99`.

Comment: Also, note that up to 16 decimal numbers (i.e `f'{num:0.16f}'`) it still print `0.9900000000000000` so I guess when you ask for 20 decimal digits it is also related to how python stores floats based on architecture `32-bit`, `64-bit` and underlying C type.

Comment: Note: iirc both in CPython and PyPy, the function that does that is actually `str` and not `print` itself. The `print` function will use `str` internally and then print the resulting string. To check that, you can see that `str(num)` in CPython with your example will return the string`"0.99"`.

Comment: @buran the `decimal` module is good for seeing the decimal expansion of floats.  note that python always uses IEEE754 binary64 "double precision" floats.  e.g. `import decimal; print(decimal.Decimal(0.99))` prints out 0.9899999999999999911182158029987476766109466552734375

Comment: @SamMason, that is good point, tnx

Comment: @SamMason *"python always uses IEEE754 binary64 "double precision" floats"* - Where can I read that?

Comment: @KellyBundy sorry, think I'm getting confused between languages!  just had a search and the closest I can get to is the [float tutorial](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/floatingpoint.html) which only says that "Almost all machines today (November 2000) use IEEE-754 floating point arithmetic".  think I'm remembering Rust which explicitly uses 754 floats.  note that, in practice, Python will use 754 floats on all commonly available systems I'm aware of, e.g. x86, x86_64, ARM, Power, RISC-V, and even MicroPython seem to use it

Comment: @SamMason Yeah, I'm pretty confident always assuming it's 754 doubles, but would've been nice to not have to assume that anymore :-). Quick search now made it look like at least MicroPython might only use single-precision... (not that I care much, I don't use it).

Comment: @KellyBundy yup! I couldn't find anything else relevant so asked https://stackoverflow.com/q/70184494/1358308 hopefully it won't get  closed as being too open-ended

Comment: @SamMason Nice, looks like we got an answer about as authoritative as possible :-)

Comment: Related: [if 0.1 has no binary representation, why I get 0.1?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30808492)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> How does Python remember the number of decimal places one used to specify a float?

It doesn't. Try this:

```
num = 0.990
print(num)
```

Notice that that also outputs `0.99`, not `0.990`.

I can't speak specifically for the `print` function, but it's common in environments that have IEEE-754 double-precision binary floating point numbers to use an algorithm that outputs only as many digits as are needed to differentiate the number from its closest "representable" neighbour. But it's much more complicated than it might seem on the surface. See [this paper on number rounding](http://ampl.com/REFS/abstracts.html#rounding) for details (associated code [here](http://netlib.sandia.gov/fp/dtoa.c) and [here](http://netlib.sandia.gov/fp/g_fmt.c)).

Sam Mason provided some great links related to this:

- From [Floating Point Arithmetic: Issues and Limitations](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/floatingpoint.html)

  This bears out the "closest representable" thing above. It starts by describing the issue in base 10 that you can't accurately represent one-third (1/3). 0.3 comes close, 0.33 comes closer, 0.333 comes even closer, but really 1/3 is an infinitely repeating series of 0.3 followed by 3s forever. In the same way, binary float point (which stores the number as a base 2 fraction rather than a base 10 fraction) can't exactly represent 0.1 (for instance), like 1/3 in base 10 it's an infinitely repeating series of digits in base 2 and anything else is an approximation. It then continues:

  > In the same way, no matter how many base 2 digits you’re willing to use, the decimal value 0.1 cannot be represented exactly as a base 2 fraction. In base 2, 1/10 is the infinitely repeating fraction
  >
  > 0.0001100110011001100110011001100110011001100110011...
  > Stop at any finite number of bits, and you get an approximation. On most machines today, floats are approximated using a binary fraction with the numerator using the first 53 bits starting with the most significant bit and with the denominator as a power of two. In the case of 1/10, the binary fraction is 3602879701896397 / 2 ** 55 which is close to but not exactly equal to the true value of 1/10.
  >
  > Many users are not aware of the approximation because of the way values are displayed. Python only prints a decimal approximation to the true decimal value of the binary approximation stored by the machine. On most machines, if Python were to print the true decimal value of the binary approximation stored for 0.1, it would have to display
  >
  > >>> 0.1
  >
  > 0.1000000000000000055511151231257827021181583404541015625
  >
  > That is more digits than most people find useful, so Python keeps the number of digits manageable by displaying a rounded value instead
  >
  > >>> 1 / 10
  >
  > 0.1
  >
  > Just remember, even though the printed result looks like the exact value of 1/10, the actual stored value is the nearest representable binary fraction.
- [The code for it in CPython](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/main/Python/dtoa.c)
- [An issue discussing it](https://bugs.python.org/issue1580) on the issues list

Comment: a better link into the Python docs might be https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/floatingpoint.html with the implementation being https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/main/Python/dtoa.c and maybe this issue https://bugs.python.org/issue1580 mentioned as well.

Comment: @SamMason - Oh, great links, thanks!

Answer (score 3):

It's not remembering. It's looking at the value it's got and deciding the best way to present it, which it thinks in this case is 0.99 because the value is as close as possible to 0.99.

If you `print(0.98999999999999999112)` it will show `0.99`, even though that is not the number of decimal places you used to specify it.