# Is sys.float_info machine specific?

Tags: python, floating-point

I would like to know if sys.float_info.max/ sys.float_info.min are fixed values which are identical on all machines or does it depend on the machine's memory or other factors (and make the value different from machine to machine). Thank you!

Comment: When asking questions like this about any programming language, you should not ask whether something may change from machine to machine but whether it may change from one implementation of the programming language to another. Two different programmers may implement Python on the same machine, even the same platform including operating system and compiler and build tools, down to exactly the same versions, but implement floating-point arithmetic within Python differently, and so they could make `sys.float_info.max` different in their two implementations.

Comment: Thanks! Do you mind to clarify how different programmers implement floating-point arithmetic differently? @EricPostpischil

Comment: One programmer might write a Python implementation that uses the hardware floating-point instructions of their target processor, likely the IEEE-754 binary64 format. Another programmer might want more precision and might use a software floating-point library to provide extended precision in floating-point.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's relatively safe to assume those values will stay the same.  They are specified by the [IEEE 754 standard for "64bit binary floats"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double-precision_floating-point_format), which all conventional Python installations use for their `float` values.

See [on what systems does Python not use IEEE-754 double precision floats](https://stackoverflow.com/q/70184494/1358308) for more details from a core developer.

As noted in the above, the only known deviation is [micropython](https://docs.micropython.org/en/latest/library/math.html) which uses 32bit binary floats instead.  However, given other constraints of micropython it's pretty safe to assume you're not going to be running there unless you know about it.  For example, lots of the standard library doesn't exist which would break most conventional packages.