# process_time() function in python not working as expected

Tags: python, windows, performance, time, execution-time

Can someone help me understand how process_time() works?
My code is

```
from time import process_time

t = process_time()


def fibonacci_of(n):
    if n in cache:  # Base case
        return cache[n]
    # Compute and cache the Fibonacci number
    cache[n] = fibonacci_of(n - 1) + fibonacci_of(n - 2)  # Recursive case
    return cache[n]


cache = {0: 0, 1: 1}
fib = [fibonacci_of(n) for n in range(1500)]
print(fib[-1])
print(process_time() - t)
```

And last print is always 0.0.
My expected result is something like 0.764891862869
Docs at https://docs.python.org/3/library/time.html#time.process_time don't help newbie me :(

I tried some other functions and reading docs. But without success.

Comment: It does output a time correctly for me. Is your code executing so quickly that the time difference is rounded to 0? Have you tried a larger `n` to see if that displays a time?

Comment: Trying using `time.process_time_ns()`

Comment: @BRemmelzwaal You are correct, 15000 fibonacci is 0.018663162. Thanks. On my second computer 15000 is 0.003125. I think it's depends on processor.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd assume this is OS dependent.  Linux lets me get down to ~5 microseconds using `process_time`, but other operating systems might well not deal well with differences this small and return zero instead.

It's for this reason that Python exposes other timers that are designed to be more accurate over shorter time scales.  Specifically, [`perf_counter`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/time.html#time.perf_counter) is specified as using:

> the highest available resolution to measure a short duration

Using this lets me measure down to ~80 nanoseconds, whether I'm using `perf_counter` or `perf_counter_ns`.

Comment: Thanks a lot! It really what i wanted. I'm using Windows 11

Answer (score 0):

As documentation suggests:

```
time.process_time() → float
```

> Return the value (in fractional seconds) of the sum of the system and user
> CPU time of the current process. It does not include time
> elapsed during sleep. It is process-wide by definition. The reference
> point of the returned value is undefined, so that only the difference
> between the results of two calls is valid.

> Use `process_time_ns()` to avoid the precision loss caused by the float type.

This last sentence is the most important and differentiates between the very precise function: `process_time_ns()` and one that is less precise but more appropriate for the long-running processes - `time.process_time()`.

It turns out that when you measure a couple nanoseconds (nano means `10**-9`) and try to express it in *seconds* dividing by `10**9`, you often go out of the precision of `float` (64 bits) and end up rounding up to zero. The [float limitations](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/floatingpoint.html) are described in the Python documentation.
To get to know more you can also read [a general introduction to precision in floating point arithmetic](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html) (ambitious) and [its peril](https://www.lahey.com/float.htm) (caveats).

Comment: Note that a float is always 64bit in CPython, so there should be enough precision to represent nanosecond differences out to over a week of run time.

Comment: @SamMason Do you have a reference to documentation on this?

Comment: as far as I know the docs are deliberately vague on this, but the [CPython source](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/3.11/Objects/floatobject.c) always uses a C `double`.  this [question of mine](https://stackoverflow.com/q/70184494/1358308) seems relevant here

Comment: Thank you for the reference. I am updating the answer.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but time.process_time() gives 0 with my code. And i read docs and tryied it before. https://imgur.com/a/txGRMES
Any ideas why?

Comment: I mean process_time_ns()

Comment: Then the question is what OS and platform you are running on?

Comment: @sophros note my "over a week" comment is based on an IEEE754 binary64 float having ~15 decimal digits of precision.  you can calculate a better bound by doing `1e-9 / (sys.float_info.epsilon * 60 * 60 * 24)` which gives ~52 days.  you can verify by adding 1e-9 onto 50 days worth of seconds (50 * 60 * 60 * 24) and checking that it's able to represent that change.  i.e. this issue is because Windows doesn't track process level time to nanosecond level precision like Linux.  Python using floats by default for time really does make sense for most people and you'll rarely need the `_ns` variants