# How to reinterpret bits of float as int in python

Tags: python, floating-point, integer, bit

I had to write code that printed out bits of floating point number (in hexadecimal). For C++, the first thing that came to mind was
`std::cout << std::hex << *reinterpret_cast<uint32_t*>(&x);`
where x is a floating point variable that stores the original number.

However, when I tried the same problem in python, I just couldn't come up with a python-ish way to solve it (using not built-in libraries is not allowed). My best attempts lead to something like this:

```
from ctypes import Union, c_uint32, c_float

class conversion(Union):
    _fields_ = [("int", c_uint32),
                ("float", c_float)]

v = conversion()
v.float = float(input())
print(hex(v.int)[2:])
```

which is basically C code.

So, is there more "python" way to do this? Did recent python versions introduce something that could be useful for this case?

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3/library/struct.html

Comment: My take is that if you're doing something sufficiently close to the metal that you need to examine the hardware representation of a float, Python isn't a good choice of language.

Comment: That doesn't even look correct, as you're losing half of the bits (from 64 to 32). What's the purpose of this exercise? Why do you want to "reinterpret bits"?  Please show an example of input and desired output.

Comment: Using a `reinterpret_cast` in C++ is not the right way to get the bits of an object. You can simply copy them with `std::memcpy`.

Comment: For the context: nothing close to metal, just an abstract task. example: input "-21.25", output "c1aa0000". Didn't know that ctypes' float size was 64 bits, i only need to work with single-precision numbers. About accessing bits, this is literally the first thing that came in mind, without any includes and stuff. Not assuming this is correct

Comment: What are you going to do with "c1aa0000"?

Comment: this is just a task from a school exam that I had. Because we were meant to solve tasks using either python or pen and paper, It was assumed that we would calculate this conversion manually - we would have to remember float's structure in memory e.t.c (because python does not provide easy bit-manipulation functionality like C does).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly, your implementation is inaccurate because float in CPython implementation is a double precision floating-point type (c++ double) so it's size is 64 bit. You have to use c_uint64 and c_double for best results

You can use the [struct](https://docs.python.org/3/library/struct.html) module to pack float to Python bytes object and then unpack it to integer value:

```
import struct
float_to_hex = lambda f: hex(struct.unpack('@Q', struct.pack('@d', f))[0])
print(float_to_hex(123.45)) # Output: 0x405edccccccccccd
```

"Python" way: you can just use the `float.hex()` method but the result will be different:

```
print(123.45.hex()) # Output: 0x1.edccccccccccdp+6
```

Comment: Re “float in python is a double precision… it's size is 64 bit”: Python does not have a formal specification or a standard and [such documentation as there is](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/floatingpoint.html?highlight=floating) leaves it to the underlying hardware to determine the floating-point format.

Comment: If you look at the `float.hex()` output, you'll see it prints something completely different from the desired output. hexfloat notation is handy, but it's not what the questioner is looking for.

Comment: @EricPostpischil in practice Python uses a IEEE754 64bit binary float (only known exception is micropython which uses 32bit float).  there's expected to be breakage when this isn't true.  https://stackoverflow.com/q/70184494/1358308

Comment: @SamMason: What is your point? That we should assume that because IEEE-754 binary64 is used almost everywhere now we should assume it is used everywhere always? Or that because it is used almost everywhere now we should state it is used by Python without cautioning people that it is not always used by Python? Neither of those is good engineering practice. It is simply bad practice to state that “X is Y” when the truth is that X is not always Y.

Comment: @EricPostpischil I prefixed with "in practice" to indicate that if you just wants something simple that works with current versions of CPython then what the answer suggests is likely fine.