# Inconsistent results between pow, np.power and direct multiplication between windows and linux in python

Tags: python, windows, floating-point, precision

Python outputs inconsistent values between methods to square a float, under windows:

```
>>> import numpy as np

>>> pow(1.3938562725915322, 2)      
1.9428353086427599

>>> np.power(1.3938562725915322, 2)
1.9428353086427599

>>> 1.3938562725915322 * 1.3938562725915322
1.9428353086427597
```

Using **Decimal** confirms that the first 2 outputs have a floating error, and the third one is not rounded:

```
>>> from decimal import Decimal

>>> np.power(Decimal(1.3938562725915322), 2)
Decimal('1.942835308642759772416265092')
```

The same code under linux outputs `1.9428353086427597` all three times.

Is there a way to make the computations consistent between platforms ?

Comment: Re “Python floats should be 64 bit on all platforms“: Python does not have a formal specification, and the Python documentation says the floating-point details are left to the Python implementation. Why do you think Python floats should be 64 bits on all platforms?

Comment: Re “Where does the difference come from ?”: Likely the multiplication is computed with a floating-point multiplication instruction, and the `pow` and `numpy.power` forms are computed with a routine that uses polynomial approximations and other complications to compute, effectively, `exp(log(x)*2)`, and that more complicated routine incurs additional rounding errors.

Comment: float 64 => https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/floatingpoint.html 15.1. Representation Error
"almost all platforms map Python floats to IEEE 754 binary64 “double precision” values. "

Comment: Edited the last part as it is less my concern and Eric is most likely right. I will dig into the code to confirm

Comment: I'd be tempted to agree with Eric as well.  only other thing I can think of is that the FPU has a different rounding mode configured by default.  not sure how to go about changing that under Windows, is `fesetround` available?

Comment: re. use of IEEE754 floats, attitude of CPython has be clarified in 3.11, see recent update to https://stackoverflow.com/q/70184494/1358308

Answer (score 2):

Functions like `pow()` inherently do not provide *exactly* consistent results.

---

Candidate source of errors:

- Converting code `1.393856272591532` to a [binary64](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double-precision_floating-point_format).
  1.393856272591532 is not exactly representable as a Python float and instead has a value of about
  1.393856272591532_219351...
- The multiply operator `*`, when the product is not exactly representable, selects one of the 2 nearest encodable values.  This may be influenced by rounding mode.  In this case the product was
  1.9428353086427596_618790...
  the closest possible answer.
- `pow(a, b)` does not certainly calculate via `a*a` when `b== 2`, but by an advanced algorithm that works well over the large set of `a, b`.  Perhaps not with the **best** answer due to the [table-maker's dilemma](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/table-maker%27s_dilemma) as what is sufficient internal calculation is difficult to assess and code.  The result of
  1.9428353086427598_839236...
  is the next largest encodable `float` after
  1.9428353086427596_618790...
- Alternatively, `pow(a, b)` may use a different algorithm, especially when `b` is a simple integer, thus rending the same answers under Linux.

---

`np.power(Decimal(1.3938562725915322), 2)` effectively affords higher precision in the product with its better
1.9428353086427597_72416265092 result.

---

> Is there a way to make the computations consistent between environments without using `Decimal` everywhere ?

Even `Decimal` will not work for all values.  OP is simply seeking exact same results even when `pow()` is allowed *some* variation in its computation.

Either

1. Do not use transcendental functions like `pow()` and use primitive operators like `*` - or
2. Tolerate approximately equal results - or
3. Re-work the problem to use integer only math.

Using higher precision types will lessen the occurrence rate of differences (when printing to the same precision), yet there are still expected.

Comment: I understand that there is no exactitude with floating operations.
I am looking for consistency between platforms with same specs, different OS. 
If it is not achievable so be it, but I also try to understand where and why.
Thanks for your help

Comment: @mxdbld Consistency with transcendental functions like `pow()` can be achieved if one is forced to use a certain algorithm, which may not be implemented in hardware and may be an inferior algorithm in the future.  Thus you can get consistency but with maybe a 100x slower code and may not be the best answer. Rather than look for _high precision_ consistency, consider tolerating minor differences.

Comment: Those floating errors are multiplied thousands of time to a point where they are unfortunately not minor in a few cases. This is not homogeneous and explodes only for certain parameters (engine is not well coded)
I could tolerate differences based on the output fields with multiple epsilons, but that would lead to  other problems.

So far, I will have to stick with a single platform to be able to identify exactly what changes between commits and refactor the code to a point where this issue is no more.

Comment: @mxdbld Curious, if the choice was between 2 systems A,B that provided the same result and another system pair C,D that provided different results (yet more accurate than A,B) , do you favor the AB systems even though less correct?  It sounds like your are trying to avoid differences at the risk of correctness.  Comparing for differences obviously easier than comparing correctness.  Good luck.

Comment: @mxdbld Thanks for that last feedback.  If a CNC machine is getting out of tolerance results due to accumulation of things like `pow(x,2)` versus `x*x`, I suggest there is a significant instability in the overall code algorithm that needs review.

Answer (score 1):

Floats in all languages are a curse in some cases for exact values.

This is because when the language gets down to the lower level it turns your value to binary. Storing floats in binary is very, very tedious and our computers do not do the best job at this. If you want to understand this topic more check out this link [fireship](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=s9F8pu5KfyM)

what chux said is the best avenue of approach. Stick with integers. If you have floating point to begin with convert them to integers, perform in your case the exponent and then you can convert them back. This will give you the most "bang for your buck" meaning precision while not limiting your range.

Here is an example with what you gave as code.

```
x = 1.3938562725915322

new_x = 1.3938562725915322 * 10000000000000000

print(new_x)

expontent_x = new_x ** 2
floating_x = expontent_x / 32

print(expontent_x)
```